# Test that hash contains specific keys and that values for those keys are not nil

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I test that a method returns a hash that contains specific keys and the values for those keys are not nil using RSpec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

something like this:

```
test_method.values_at("key1", "key2").should_not include(nil)
```

Comment: this won't work if one of the hash's value is actually `nil`. `hash.keys.should =~ [:key1, :key2]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

I'd write:

```
describe MyObject do
  describe "#my_method" do
    subject(:my_method) { MyObject.new.my_method }

    it { is_expected.to be_a_kind_of(Hash) }
    specify { expect(my_method.keys).to include(:key1, :key2) }
    specify { expect(my_method.values).not_to include(nil) }
  end
end
```

It may happen that you have to use keys in inverted commas "key1", "key2". Otherwise it may throw error.